# Can't connect to the Remote Desktop Gateway server

Tags: rdp, windows-10, remote-desktop-gateway

My saved RDP connections through Remote Desktop Gateway server suddenly stopped working with error message:

> Your computer can't connect to the Remote Desktop Gateway server.
>   Contact your network administrator for assistance

However I can connect directly by IP without RDP Gateway

Windows 10 Pro v.1601

Comment: FInally I found a solution - create a DWORD-32 key `RDGClientTransport` with value `1` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awesome. I had one client with issues and couldn't figure out the solution. Tried AV, updates, etc.

> create a DWORD-32 key RDGClientTransport with value 1 at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client

Finally resolved the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue, except when it was set to 1, I couldn't connect. Flipped it to 0 and am now able to connect. See here: https://syscenramblings.wordpress.com/2017/11/27/strange-case-of-the-failed-remote-desktop-gateway/